# Django/postgresql how to make it throw integrity errors?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have this issue: http://www.goalbrecht.com/2014/09/django-get_or_create-makes-duplicates/

Author gives good solution but I am stuck at trying to find out how to make postgresql throw integrity error for duplicate key? Here is code from site:

```
class ExtendedManager(models.Manager):

  # Note that this new method only works if database constraints are set up to throw
  # integrity errors due to unique constraints in the database tables.
  def get_or_create(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:  
      return super().get_or_create(*args, **kwargs)

    except IntegrityError as e:  # DB reports that an object with these params already exists! 
      # Try again - this time, the get() should succeed and we're good to go.
      # If it fails again with an integrity error, send it to the caller
      return super().get_or_create(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I add objects it doesn't throw any error, it just creates duplicates even though unique=True is in the model.

Comment: That code is unnecessary (now, at least, I don't know about when that blog post was written), as `get_or_create()` [already does that](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cc8c02fa0fa2119704d1c39ca8509850aef84acc/django/db/models/query.py#L492). So your problem is simply that the database is not respecting your constraints. There's not enough information in your question to address that, but usually it's because of unapplied or mis-applied migrations.

Comment: thanks, will reset db and hopefully this will fix it.